# The bot can't retrieve the id, and check status. The output is empty when i type #status in discord

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command(name='status') 
async def status(current): 
    status = None

    for member in current.guild.members:
    #fetches all members in the current guild
        if str(member.id) == current.message.content:
        #checks if the stringified id of the member is the one the bot is looking for
            status = member.status
            
    if status == discord.Status.online:
        online_embed = discord.Embed(title='awa is online', description='', color=0xf6e5e5)
        await current.send(embed=online_embed)
```

The bot can't get the member id, and check it's status

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: i don't think i have any enabled

Comment: That's the issue. Take a look at the intents page: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should enable intents at the begging of your code:

```py
#example
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", intents=intents)
```

and then in your command you should specify an argument because the `message.content` will look like this: `#status {id}` and you don't want that I suppose. Your command code should look something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def status(current, content: str):
    status = None
    for member in current.guild.members:
        if str(member.id) == content:
            status = member.status
            break
    if status == discord.Status.online:
        online_embed = discord.Embed(
            title="awa is online", description="", color=0xF6E5E5
        )
        await current.send(embed=online_embed)
```

Also note that I added `break` statement in `if status == discord.Status.online:` to prevent code from going through members when it already have found one that is matching the requirements.

Comment: When comparing entities it's preferred to use the `is` keyword instead of `==`, so `if status == discord.Status.online` -> `if status is discord.Status.online:`

Comment: `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: content is a required argument that is missing.` i got this as a result hm

Comment: How are you using this command? like this: `#status {your id here}` or like this `#status`?

Comment: It works, but is there a way to avoid #status {id}, but instead #status <@mention>.
`mention = f'<@!{client.user.id}>'` with `if check.author.content = mention:`. putting `mention == str(member.id)` together is what i have tried